# How to input variable text from list in Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, variables, automation

I'm looking for a way to input Google research from a keyword list.

It will work as cycles, cycle 1 = "keyword1", cycle 2 = "keyword2"...

Here the code in loop :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def main():

    driver.get('https://www.google.com')

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('keyword1')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(2)

main()

while True:
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for searching a list of keywords.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
keyword_list = ["keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"] # Your list of keywords

def googleSearch(keyword):
    ''' This function searches Google for the given keyword '''
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(keyword)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(2)

for keyword in keyword_list: # This runs thru your keywordlist keyword by keyword
    googleSearch(keyword) # and this run the function to search for the keyword
```